# Azure Logic Apps : Send Email Body Validation Error when Attaching CSV file

Tags: azure-logic-apps

[image: Logic App Send Email Element]

This step is triggered by the arrival of a file in a given folder. There is a Get Blob Content step before the Send Email which picks up the details of the file.

When I add a file to the folder the file is correctly detected and is successfully sent as an attachment to the email. This works with every type of file that I have tried except for .csv files (which, of course, is the type I'm working with).

When a csv file is added to folder, the logic app fails at the Send Email step and gives the following error:

[image: Logic App Error output]

Here's the complete flow diagram of steps in the logic app. I don't think that the last 2 steps impact on this problem.

[image: Logic App flow diagram]

I'd be grateful for any help on this. Thanks.

Comment: I believe you are using `Azure communicative Service Email` connector for sending email?

Comment: Are you using `When a blob is added or modified (properties only)` trigger or `Get blob content` action before send email action?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the Azure Email Commincation Service.
I'm also using the 'When a blob is added or modified (properties only) V2' trigger followed by the 'Get blob content using path (V2)' action. These precede the Send Email action that is shown.

Comment: Flow diagram of Logic App now added.

Comment: The name of the file, which step is that coming from because the pill doesn’t match any names of any preceding step.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. When you say 'pill' what are you referring too? If the file name is incorrect, why does this work with other file types but not csv?

Comment: @jhTuppeny Can you please confirm if it is working for json files?

Comment: json files fail too. It appears that it's not the file content that causes the error but the extension. I send the same text file with txt, csv and json extentions. 
The file with a txt file worked and the same file with csv and json extensions didn't.

Comment: @jhTuppeny It is not working for json and csv files because content-type of these files received in the output of `When a blob is added or modified (properties only) (V2)` is `application/octet-stream` which is not a supported MIME type for Azure Communication services Email connector

Comment: @Ikhtesam Afrin thanks for that. Is there a way around this or is there a different Email service that I can use?

Comment: @jhTuppeny I am able to get the attachment using `Office 365 Outlook` connector like [this](https://i.imgur.com/7dqPI9Z.png)

Comment: @Ikhtesam Afrin Thanks - I will take a look at this.

Answer (score 1):

> Email body validation error. See property 'attachments[0].attachmentType'

I am also getting this error for both .json and .csv file in Consumption as well as in Standard logic app. I have noticed for .csv file, content type is passed as ***text/csv*** in result of `Get blob content using path (V2)` action which is an allowed attachment type for ***Azure Communication services Email connector*** as per the [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/concepts/email/email-attachment-allowed-mime-types#allowed-attachment-types).

Whereas  in case of .json file,  output of `Get blob content using path (V2)` action provides content type as `application/octet-stream` which is not a supported attachment type.

I believe, it is because ***Azure Communication services Email connector*** is currently in public preview.

[image]

Alternatively, you use ***Office 365 Outlook*** connector which works well for all type of files.

[image]

***Output***-

[image]

[image]

*You can raise an issue with the product team.*

Comment: Thanks very much for taking the time to answer my question.

Comment: I have had a response to this problem from Microsoft support. They have confirmed the bug and have suggested it will be fixed when the non-preview version is released.

Comment: @jhTuppeny glad that the issue is been identified